# package.json file won't persist in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker environment. I have made a Dockerfile which builds my image. Everything seems to work fine except for the issue that **my package.json file won't persist inside the container**. It seems as if it is getting removed somewhere. What I am doing wrong? Here is my Docker file content:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN groupadd -r webuser && useradd -r -g webuser webuser && mkdir /home/webuser/ && chown webuser:webuser /home/webuser/

# install curl, apache, php
RUN sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    curl \
    git-core \
    apache2 \
    php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl \
    php5.6-bz2 php5.6-zip && \
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

# install PHPUnit
RUN curl -L https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar && \
    chmod +x phpunit.phar && \
    mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit

ADD package.json /var/www/html/package.json

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN chown -R webuser:webuser /var/www/html

USER webuser

# install node js 6
RUN NVM_DIR="/home/webuser/.nvm" && \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash && \
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && \
    nvm install 6 && \
    npm install -g webpack && \
    npm install

RUN echo 'export NVM_DIR="/home/webuser/.nvm"\n\
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"'\
>> /home/webuser/.bashrc

COPY src /var/www/html/

USER root

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we need to have the `package.json` file within the source directory. Copying `package.json` separately and running the `npm install` pattern is used to make use of docker's caching system.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ADD command to the following :

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
ADD package.json /var/www/html
```

Also make sure the package.json is present in the

Comment: No it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

    ADD package.json /var/www/html/package.json

    RUN groupadd -r webuser && useradd -r -g webuser webuser && mkdir /home/webuser/ && chown webuser:webuser /home/webuser/

    # install curl, apache, php
    RUN sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        apt-get -y update && \
        apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties && \
        add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && \
        apt-get -y update && \
        apt-get install -y --force-yes \
        curl \
        git-core \
        apache2 \
        php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl \
        php5.6-bz2 php5.6-zip && \
        php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
        php composer-setup.php && \
        php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
        mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

    # install PHPUnit
    RUN curl -L https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar && \
        chmod +x phpunit.phar && \
        mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit && \
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit



    WORKDIR /var/www/html

    RUN chown -R webuser:webuser /var/www/html

    USER webuser

    # install node js 6
    RUN NVM_DIR="/home/webuser/.nvm" && \
        curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash && \
        [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && \
        nvm install 6 && \
        npm install -g webpack && \
        npm install

    RUN echo 'export NVM_DIR="/home/webuser/.nvm"\n\
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"'\
    >> /home/webuser/.bashrc

    COPY src /var/www/html/

    USER root

    EXPOSE 80

    CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

i have executed your Dockerfile and had the same problem. It works if the ADD is at the beginning of the Dockerfile. But there are some other problems. The build process is stopping right after

```
 chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

it wont install PHPUnit and nodeJS, set owner of the www directory and so on.

Maybe you should chain the whole RUN into one.

Comment: @mahadazad do you have the file in the same folder as you Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, the file exists in the same place where the Dockerfile is.

Comment: @mahadazad maybe the statement:  COPY src /var/www/html/ overrides the file? try to build without it.

Comment: But I have seen this pattern in many docker files. It works well there.

Comment: @mahadazad maybe inspect the building process in the bash step by step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124521/discussion-between-mahadazad-and-gabbax0r).